# get key name & key value from json

Tags: java, json, cordova

I'm totally new to java.  How do I get the key name & key value of this jsonobject & pass it to my increment method?

```
args = {'property_name':1}


private boolean handlePeopleIncrement(JSONArray args, final CallbackContext cbCtx) {

    JSONObject json_array = args.optJSONObject(0);

    mixpanel.getPeople().increment(key_name, key_value);
    cbCtx.success();
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now I'm getting the error:

```
Object cannot be converted to Number  
Number value = json_array.get(key);
```

-

```
private boolean handlePeopleIncrement(JSONArray args, final CallbackContext cbCtx) {
     JSONObject json_array = args.optJSONObject(0);

    Iterator<?> keys = json_array.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        Number value = json_array.get(key);
       // System.out.println("Key: " + key);
       // System.out.println("Value: " + json_array.get(key));
    }

    mixpanel.getPeople().increment(key, value);
    cbCtx.success();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That depends on what `JSON` library you're using, if `json_array` is an `org.json.JSONObject` you can use the `keys()` method to get the keys and  use those keys to get the corresponding values.

Answer (score 15):

Try using this

```
JSONObject json_array = args.optJSONObject(0);

Iterator<?> keys = json_array.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + key);
    System.out.println("Value: " + json_array.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as your new to Java and JSON is one of the most famous data interchange language out there, I recommend you to understand the parsing and the structure of JSON thoroughly [this example](http://deepakbaliga.com/index.php/2015/09/19/json-is-easy/).

```
for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()){
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

This will fetch you the set of Keys in the JSON.